# Image not uploading

Tags: php, html, image

i am having trouble trying to upload an image to a website, and update the database with the address of the image. All of the other fields are being correctly added to the database, except for the image address, and the image is not being saved in the images folder. I have absolutely no idea whats wrong, and when i try to upload an image it echoes there was a problem uploading your file. Thanks a lot for the help.

```
<?php

 if($_REQUEST['submit'])
 {       
   function isChecked($chkname,$value)
       {
         if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]))
         {
            foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval)
            {
                if($chkval == $value)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }


  $target = "~start/B7/images/";
  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

  $age = $_POST["age"];
  $brand = $_POST["brand"];
  $model = $_POST["model"];
  $price = $_POST["price"];
  $vechicleType = $_POST["vechicleType"];
  $fuelType = $_POST["fuelType"];
  $transmition = $_POST["transmition"];
  $doorsNumbers = $_POST["doorsNumbers"];
  $mileage = $_POST["mileage"];  
  $pic = ($_FILES['photo']['name']);



  //Connect to the server
  $con = mysql_connect("*********", "*********", "*********")
  or die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());

  // Select database
  mysql_select_db("*********", $con)
  or die('Could not select database');

// Select all the names from the database   
$checkName = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

while ($number = mysql_fetch_array($checkName))
{
  $index = 0;   
  if (($number['user_name'] == $name) && ($number['password'] == $password) 
      || isset($_SESSION['test']))
  {
    $index = 1;
    $_SESSION['test']=$name;
$_SESSION['id']=$number['user_id'];   
   }
 }


  // Select all the names from the database   
  $checkName = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM used_cars");  




 if (!empty($model)) 
  {
    if(isChecked('extras', 'leather'))
       $leather = "yes";


if(isChecked('extras', 'airCon'))
   $airCon = "yes";

if(isChecked('extras', 'satNav'))
   $satNav = "yes";

if(isChecked('extras', 'parkingSensors'))
   $parking = "yes";



$insert1="INSERT INTO used_cars (manufacturer, model, price, image, vehicleType,
age, transmission, fuelType, doorsNumber, user_id, colour, mileage,
leatherSeat, navigatorSystem, parkingSensor, airConditioner) VALUES ('$brand', '$model', '$price', '$pic', '$vechicleType', 
'$age', '$transmition', '$fuelType', '$doorsNumbers', '$user_id', 
'$colour', '$mileage', '$leather', '$satNav', '$parking', '$airCon')";    




     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
     {
       //Tells you if its all ok
       echo "The file was uploaded";
     }

     else
     {
       //Gives an error if its not
       echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
     }



   }

   else
   {
     echo 'Please fill in all fields';
   }




  mysql_close($con);
  } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you setting the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

Comment: so you have to set this enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @dleiftah ok i added the enctype, and i am now getting ~start/B7/images/car-news.jpg, which i am echoing, which means $target is correct, but i still receive there was a problem uploading the file.

Comment: @AdeelMughal i have done that now, but it still doesnt work

Comment: Check permissions on your images directory.

Comment: Does the webserver user have write permissions on the target directory?

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($_FILES);` and post the output here? I believe it should be an array, in which case your image would be in `$_FILES[0]['photo']['tmp_name']`

Comment: @dqhendricks its just part of the path. It definitely has to be there.

Comment: @augustknight Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => used-cars.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpDAlEAQ [error] => 0 [size] => 16752 ) )

Comment: What does `file_exists('~start/B7/images/');` return?

Comment: Better yet ... `var_dump(is_writable('~start/B7/images/'));`

Comment: @dqhendricks it returns nothing

Comment: @akshai5050 if it returns nothing, then that means that folder does not exist. you are most likely using the wrong path.

Comment: @dleiftah it returns bool(false)

Comment: @dqhendricks do i need to put a forwardslash before ~start ?

Comment: @akshai5050 I do not know where your script is located, or what path you are trying to reach. No way to know what is needed to fix your situation. If you put a slash at the beginning, the path will go from the root folder, otherwise it will be a relative path from where your php script is located.

Comment: @dqhendricks i added the forward slash, but i still get bool(false)

Comment: yes, i want to go from the root folder

Comment: `echo realpath($target);` to see exactly where the file is going ... make sure the directory is writable ... That solves your issue ...

Comment: @akshai5050 if you ftp into your server, and go to the folder you wish the image to be held in, is `/~start/B7/images` what is in your ftp client's path?

Comment: @dleiftah that doesn't return anything

Comment: @dqhendricks I don't use ftp. But the address bar of my browser shows this when i am viewing a file called News1.jpg: domain.com/~start/B7/images/News1.jpg

Comment: that could mean anything depending on your url rewrites. how do you upload files to your website?

Comment: @dqhendricks the files are placed into a public_html folder in my filestore

Comment: @dqhendricks so the url for index.html in the public_html folder would be domain.com/~start/B7/index.html

Comment: @dqhendricks the upload script is also placed in the public_html folder, while the images folder is in the public_html folder as well.

Comment: if that is the case, then your path should probably be `images/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained further in the comments, your path should probably be `images/`